# VBA - Avoid error when cancel getfolder

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a basic error when I cancel the selection of a folder. I just want to Exit Sub when press the cancel button.

[image]

I'm using the following code

```
Set recsFolder = fso.GetFolder(Functions.GetFolder("C:\"))

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim Fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set Fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With Fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set Fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: on which line are you falling when you click debug?

Comment: its because you have recsFolder out of function. Try to insert it into function and them compare Fldr to false? or whatever it is if you press cancel

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion from one of the best source : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/browsefolder.aspx

```
Function BrowseFolder(Title As String, _
                Optional InitialFolder As String = vbNullString, _
                Optional InitialView As Office.MsoFileDialogView = msoFileDialogViewList)_
                As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim InitFolder As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = Title
        .InitialView = InitialView
        If Len(InitialFolder) > 0 Then
            If Dir(InitialFolder, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
                InitFolder = InitialFolder
                If Right(InitFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                    InitFolder = InitFolder & "\"
                End If
                .InitialFileName = InitFolder
            End If
        End If
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        V = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            V = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
    BrowseFolder = CStr(V)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happen in

```
Set recsFolder = fso.GetFolder(Functions.GetFolder("C:\"))
```

Because your function `GetFolder` returns an empty string when you cancel the folder selection

QUick solution, just change your logic to this:

```
Dim strReturned As String
strReturned = Functions.GetFolder("C:\")

If strReturned <> "" Then
    Set recsFolder = fso.GetFolder(strReturned)
End If
```

to bypass the `Set recsFolder` if the folder is empty

Answer (score 0):

I've read all of your answers and thank you for them, but I couldn't manage to apply them. Instead I have used the error handling (which I know I should avoid, but it won't damage the code).

```
        On Error GoTo ErrHandlr:
    Set recsFolder = fso.GetFolder(Functions.GetFolder("C:\"))
ErrHandlr:
Exit Sub
```